# javascript onclick failing on a function call

Tags: javascript, html

I have this html...

```
<a onclick="search.analysisSelect('2');" href="javascript:void(0);">A Product</a>
```

...And whenever I click that link in the browser (IE, FF, and Chrome), it fails. It tells me that the function does not exist. However, if I type that exact function call into the console of firebug, it runs fine. So the function does exist.

**Exact error message:** "search.analysisSelect is not a function"

I have recently changed the "search" object name to "searchTab" and the onclick works fine.

Why is the onclick failing for the search object? I am baffled...

Here is the search object. This is stored in a separate js file loaded when the page loads.

```
var search = {
    analysisSelect: function(pub) {
        $("#tabs").tabs("select", "#analysis");

        analysisGrid.refreshSlickGrid(pub, '0', '1', '0');
    }
};
```

Oh, I forgot to mention that I also have an init() funciton defined in the search object, which is called on an onclick event for another html element, and that fires off with no issues. Wtf...

Comment: So are you saying that your program works with Firebug enabled, but fails when it is disabled?

Comment: Can we haz teh codez plz? There is always http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @jsalonen No. The onclick fails regardless if firebug is enabled or disabled. I can call the function through the firebug console, proving that the function does exist.

Comment: Is your onclick really just `search` and not `searchTab`? The onclick event looks at a glance like it is looking for something in `search` which doesn't seem to exist in your shown code... And you definitely copied the function call with copy and paste into firebug to get it to fail? Typing it can lead to instinctive correcting of errors sometimes...

Comment: I can only assume you have object or global variable declared somewhere named `search`, overriding the actual object you mean. Search your code for *search* and see for yourself. Can be also element in your HTML with such ID.

Comment: @Chris Currently, on the webpage, it is searchTab. I changed the code to search for this question, since that is how it is failing.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I did a search on my code to see if I had any other global variables named search and could not find any. Also, when I change that object name to searchTab, and then type search into the console of firebug, nothing returns, proving that it dosen't exist...

Comment: What is the exact and full error when you name it `search`? Can you post it here please?

Comment: @ShadowWizard error message edited into the OP...

Comment: So it means `search` is defined, but doesn't contain function called "analysisSelect" - when you do `onclick="alert(search);"` what do you see in the alert?

Answer (score 1):

Where did you define `search.analysisSelect()`? It should be defined before the anchor tag.

generally using inline javascripts is not a good idea, consider using an external javascript file and bind that function to the anchor `onclick` event like this:

```
window.onload = function() { // ensures that the document is loaded before finding the anchor element
    // assign an Id to the anchor tag like this: <a id="idOfAnchorTag" href="#">A Product</a>
    var elem = getElementById('idOfAnchorTag');
    elem.onclick = function() {
        search.analysisSelect('2');
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no doubt in my mind that the function is defined before the anchor tag is written.

Comment: I can't say what's exactly wrong with inline function call in your markup, but if it works in firebug console, then you would try using the snippet I posted in my answer either in an external js file or within a script tag.

Answer (score 1):

There is some strange javascript voodoo going on in the inline event handler.  `search` is not being resolved to `window.search`, it is hitting something else and I don't know what it is.

See http://jsfiddle.net/yPhZ8/

However, I can tell you how to fix it.  Use `window.search` instead.

```
<a onclick="window.search.analysisSelect('2');" href="javascript:void(0);">A Product</a>
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/yPhZ8/1/

Comment: This is essentially the solution I came up with in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this exact problem today. Turns out, you can't have an HTML element with an ID the same as the function.

Don't ask me why, I'd just say it has something to do with extremely lazy parsing.

My Example:

```
<dd style="margin-left: 2px;"><input type="button" name="info[add_benefit]" id="add_benefit" value="{L_ADD_BENEFIT}" class="button2" 
                                    style="width: 100%;" onclick="add_benefit();" />&nbsp;</dd>
```

The onclick method would return an error saying that the function didn't exist. Apparently it thought the button itself was the function, but the button was a button, hence the error.